# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header name 'first_name' not found. Available columns

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, hibernate

**'When I run with spring boot application I am getting the below error, Here I am trying to parse CSV file data into the database.'**

```
    'Failed to complete request: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header name 'first_name' not found. Available columns 
    are: [first_name;last_name;account_type;email;address;zipcode;Location]
    2022-10-14 19:29:31.510 ERROR 5256 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header name 'first_name' not found. Available columns are: [first_name;last_name;account_type;email;address;zipcode;Location]] with root cause.'
```

My Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_details")
public class AccountDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "account_type")
    private String accountType;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String adddress;
    @Column(name = "zipcode")
    private String zipcode;
    @Column(name = "Location")
    private String location;

    
    public AccountDetails() {
        super();
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }


    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }


    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }


    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    public String getAccountType() {
        return accountType;
    }


    public void setAccountType(String accountType) {
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }


    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public String getAdddress() {
        return adddress;
    }


    public void setAdddress(String adddress) {
        this.adddress = adddress;
    }


    public String getZipcode() {
        return zipcode;
    }


    public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }


    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }


    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    
   
}


My respostiry class:

    package com.alavu.fileupload_in_springboot_csv_to_db.entity;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountDetails,Integer> {
     
}

My controller class:

    @RestController
public class BankController {
    @Autowired
    AccountRepository service; 
    
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String uploadData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        List<AccountDetails> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
        InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
        CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
        settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
        CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
        List<Record> parseAllRecords =  parser.parseAllRecords(inputStream);
        parseAllRecords.forEach(record->{
            AccountDetails account = new AccountDetails();
            // account.setAccountNumber(Integer.parseInt(record.getString("account_number")));
            account.setFirstName(record.getString("first_name"));
            account.setLastName(record.getString("last_name"));
            account.setAccountType(record.getString("account_type"));
            account.setAdddress(record.getString("address"));
            account.setEmail(record.getString("email"));
            account.setZipcode(record.getString("zipcode"));
            account.setLocation(record.getString("Location"));
            accountList.add(account);
        });
        service.saveAll(accountList);
        return "Upload Successfull !!!";
    }
}


   
CSV File data:

first_name;last_name;account_type;email;address;zipcode;Location
smith;12se74;rb9012;Rachel;Booker;Sales;Manchester
rahul;04ap67;lg2070;Laura;Grey;Depot;London
```

postman Response:

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header name 'first_name' not found. Available columns are: [first_name;last_name;account_type;email;address;zipcode;Location]\r\n\tat com.univocity.parsers.common.record.RecordMetaDataImpl.getMetaData(RecordMetaDataImpl.java:50)\r\n\tat com.univocity.parsers.common.record.RecordMetaDataImpl.metadataOf(RecordMetaDataImpl

Can you please help me to resolve this issue at earliest.???

Comment: Can you share the service method and repository class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
    account.setFirstName(record.getString("firstName"));
    account.setLastName(record.getString("lastName"));
    account.setAccountType(record.getString("accountType"));
    account.setAdddress(record.getString("address"));
    account.setEmail(record.getString("email"));
    account.setZipcode(record.getString("zipcode"));
    account.setLocation(record.getString("Location"));
    accountList.add(account);
```